# chown for files generated by a process running as root

Tags: permissions, fedora, chown

I have a Fedora server running an application as root (via sudo). The users operating the application can extract data with "Save as" menu from inside the application. However, the generated files has the owner "root", group "root" and permission 600. So the users then need to contact admin to claim their files. Any suggestion to make it simpler?

I thought of adding chown to sudoers so users can chown files on their Desktop, but what if they create a hard link on Desktop pointing to other places?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) on the directory: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/02/sticky-bit-on-directory-file/ and set the group on the target directory.